# Dynamically adding JavaScript inside an Iframe and calling it using elements inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an Iframe set up like so:

```
<iframe>
    <html>
        <head>
            <style></style>
            <script></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        </body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

Data from textboxes is being inserted in to the script and body tags of the Iframe on the page load.

The program will allow user inputted Javascript and HTML to parse inside the iframe.

Looking at the code view, my example function appears when I type it in:

```
<iframe>
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
            </style>
            <script>
                function say(message) {
                    alert(message);
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1 onclick="say('hello');">Click me</h1>
        </body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

However, when I click on the  tag , this message displays in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: say is not defined
```

Could someone tell me why this is happening, and how I can resolve the issue?

Kind Regards,
Daniel Watson

*EDIT:* Corrected an error in my markup, this was not an issue but rather an error in trying to retype the problem for the question.

Also, the JavaScript function is being inserted in to the Iframe fine with this code:

```
$("iframe").contents().find('head script').html(data['js']);
```

Comment: Not sure it's related but you should fix the opening `<html>` tag. It is currently a close `</html>` tag.

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed? I have a similar issue...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
        <style>
            function say(message) {
                alert(message);
            }
        </style>
        <script></script>
```

you should have

```
        <style></style>
        <script>
            function say(message) {
                alert(message);
            }
        </script>
```

Also, you have two closing `html` tags but no opening one.

Answer (score 0):

So many errors...

### iframes are empty!

You cannot put contents inside an iframe. What you want is [srcdoc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

```
<iframe srcdoc="etc"></iframe>
```

### Start tags don't have slashes!

```
</html>
```

Should be

```
<html>
```

### It's not a style!

```
<style>
    function say(message) {
        alert(message);
    }
</style>
```

Is wrong. Make it:

```
<script>
    function say(message) {
        alert(message);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Considering OP gets an error message when clicking on a tag, I'd say the code in the post is just pseudo code, OP's real code is probably created properly...?

Comment: Yes. "The program will allow user inputted Javascript and HTML to parse inside the iframe."